# Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight shelltoast notiification applist icon click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I am trying to upgrade my Windows phone 8 app to Windows phone 8.1 silver light app. The problem is that in Windows Phone 8 clicking on the App List icon of the toast notification navigated you to the Application Main Page and clicking on the toast notification navigated you to a different page based on the navigation URI. This is not happening in 8.1 silver light as clicking on the app list icon navigates you to the navigation Uri of the first toast message instead of launching the main application page. Is there any way to have the older behavior in 8.1 silver light or is there any way to map the app list icon in the toast message to a URI. 
Thanks